# Universal poset for cardinals $\kappa \geq \aleph_0$

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, posets

Given a cardinal $\kappa\geq \aleph_0$, is there a poset $(P,\leq)$ with $|P| = \kappa$ such that every poset of cardinality $\kappa$ can be order-embedded into $(P,\leq)$?

Comment: For $\kappa=\omega$, the [countable generic poset](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/388815/what-is-the-theory-of-the-random-poset) works. Also, such a poset exists for any uncountable $\kappa$ such that $\kappa^{<\kappa}=\kappa$ for general model-theoretic reasons (this condition ensures the existence of a saturated model of any countable theory, in particular the theory of the generic poset (which is the model completion of the theory of posets), of cardinality $\kappa$). I don’t know what happens for other cardinalities.

Comment: Actually, the requirements for the existence of universal models should be weaker than for the existence of saturated models, as for limit $\kappa$, one can take a limit of an elementary chain where each model is saturated over its predecessor. I don’t have the time to think about it now, but perhaps this works for all uncountable $\kappa$ such that $2^{<\kappa}=\kappa$, or something like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easy case occurs when $\kappa^{<\kappa}=\kappa$. Under GCH, this includes every regular cardinal. As Emil mentions in the comments, the result for this case follows from general model-theoretic considerations of saturated models.

But for definiteness, let me describe a concrete construction. We construct a universal partial order in a process of length $\kappa$. Start with nothing $P_0=\emptyset$. At each stage $\alpha$, consider all possible subsets $A,B,C\subseteq P_\alpha$ each of size less than $\kappa$, such that every element of $A$ is strictly below every element of $B$, and no element of $C$ is below an element of $A$ or above an element of $B$. Add a new point to $P_{\alpha+1}$ that is above every element of $A$, below every element of $B$, and incomparable with every element of $C$. That is, for each possible way of relating to a given fewer than $\kappa$ many elements we have so far, we add such a point realizing that possibility. Since $\kappa^{<\kappa}=\kappa$, there are at most $\kappa$ many $A,B,C$, and so we have added at most $\kappa$ many points at each stage, and so inductively every $P_\alpha$ has size at most $\kappa$. At limit stages, we take the union of everything we've added up to that stage.

Consider the ultimate order $P_\kappa$ that we've built by stage $\kappa$. This order has size $\kappa$, and I claim it is universal for all orders of size $\kappa$. To see this, suppose that you have an order $\langle Q,\leq\rangle$ of size $\kappa$. Enumerate it in a $\kappa$ sequence $q_\alpha$ for $\alpha<\kappa$, and build an embedding into $P_\kappa$ in stages. We will ensure that each $q_\alpha$ finds its image in $P_{\alpha+1}$.

At each stage, $q_\alpha$ relates to the previous elements $q_\beta$ for $\beta<\alpha$ in a certain way — above some, below others, and incomparable with the rest. But at stage $\alpha$ in the universal construction, we added a point of exactly that type relative to the images of those points. So there is a point in $P_{\alpha+1}$ to which to map $q_\alpha$ so as to extend the embedding one more step. Thus, $Q$ embeds into $P_\kappa$, and so our partial order is universal for all orders of size continuum.

The model we've constructed is not only universal, but also homogeneous, since any given embedding of a less-than-size-$\kappa$ order can be extended. But if CH fails, then it is easy to see that there can be no such order of size $\aleph_1$, since for a given copy of $\mathbb{Q}$ it would have to realize all the cuts, but there are too many. More generally, whenever $2^\gamma>\kappa$ for some $\gamma<\kappa$, then there would have to be an antichain of size $\gamma$, and every subset of it would have to have a point above it and not the other points in the antichain, but there are too many subsets. It is much more subtle, however, to rule out merely universal orders of these sizes.

To get an idea of the difficulties, consider the following paper of Kojman and Shelah concerning the corresponding case of universal linear orders.

- *Kojman, Menachem; Shelah, Saharon*, [**Nonexistence of universal orders in many cardinals**](https://doi.org/10.2307/2275437), J. Symb. Log. 57, No. 3, 875-891 (1992). [ZBL0790.03036](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0790.03036).

They prove, for example (theorem 3.6), that if $\aleph_1<\lambda=\text{cof}(\lambda)<2^{\aleph_0}$, then there is no $\lambda$-universal linear order of size $\lambda$.

I am unsure of the extent to which those results apply to partial orders.

Comment: I'm not sure of the argument with $\eta^{<\eta}>\eta$. First, the condition you get is not "every subset of it of size less than $\eta$ would have to have a point above those nodes and no others in the antichain", but only that for all subsets $A,B$ of size $<\eta$ such that $A<B$, there is a point that separates them. Since a single point can separate many such pairs, it's not clear to me that this requires $\eta^{<\eta}$ distinct points. As a case in point, the number of cuts on a linear order of size $\eta$ is at most $\mathrm{ded}(\eta)$, which may be smaller than the naive bound $2^\eta$.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right. I have edited.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins In Komjath-Shelah paper, one should require $\aleph_1<\lambda$, and not $\aleph_0<\lambda$. See also my answer.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the correction. I have edited. Also, thank you for your refined answer.

Answer (score 8):

For consistency of non-CH with the existence of a universal linear order at $\aleph_1$ see Shelah's paper  [Independence results](https://shelah.logic.at/files/95935/100.pdf):

[image]

It is also easy to build models of non-CH in which there are no universal linear orders of size $\aleph_1$. See the remark stated below Theorem 4.7.

The same also hold for posets, by essentially the same arguments as above, but also see [Universality for Orders and Graphs Which Omit Large  Substructures](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/notre-dame-journal-of-formal-logic/volume-47/issue-2/Universality-for-Orders-and-Graphs-Which-Omit-Large-Substructures/10.1305/ndjfl/1153858648.full):

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The affirmative answer for all infinite cardinals under GCH was proved by Bjarni Jónsson, Universal relational systems, Math. Scand. 4 (1956), 193-208.

> THEOREM 3.4. *There exists an* $\aleph_0$-*universal partially ordered system. Moreover, if the Generalized Continuum Hypothesis holds, and if* $\alpha$ *is any positive ordinal, then there exists an* $\aleph_\alpha$-*universal partially ordered system.*

Answer (score 7):

Such universal posets exist for all infinite cardinals $\kappa$ such that $2^{<\kappa}=\kappa$.

[Thus, in particular, they exist whenever $\kappa=\beth_\alpha$ for a limit ordinal $\alpha$. In contrast, it is [consistent with ZFC](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4565207) (under some large cardinal assumptions) that there are no uncountable cardinals $\kappa$ such that $\kappa^{<\kappa}=\kappa$ as in [Joel’s answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/453305); notice that $\kappa^{<\kappa}=\kappa$ iff $\kappa$ is regular and $2^{<\kappa}=\kappa$. Also, this result implies that under GCH, universal posets exist in all infinite cardinalities, as mentioned in [bof’s answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/453327).]

For $\kappa=\aleph_0$, we can take the [countable generic poset](https://mathoverflow.net/q/388815) $G$, i.e., the Fraïssé limit of the class of finite posets.

For uncountable $\kappa$, we can use the following general result from model theory:

> **Theorem.** Let $T$ be a complete theory with an infinite model, and $\kappa>\|T\|$ a cardinal such that $2^{<\kappa}=\kappa$. Then there exists a $\kappa^+$-universal model of $T$ of cardinality $\kappa$.

Here, a model $\def\A{\mathfrak A}\def\B{\mathfrak B}\A\models T$ is $\lambda$-universal if every model $\B\models T$ of size $<\lambda$ *elementarily embeds* in $\A$. Also, $\|T\|$ denotes the cardinality of the language of $T$, defined as $\aleph_0$ by fiat for finite languages.

We apply the theorem here with $T$ being the complete theory of $G$: then a $\kappa^+$-universal model of $T$ is a universal poset as in the question, because every poset of cardinality $\le\kappa$ embeds in a model of $T$ of the same cardinality (i.e., $T$ is a model companion of the theory of posets; this follows by compactness from the fact that each finite poset embeds in $G$).

Since the Theorem is lesser known than the existence of saturated models under the stronger assumption $\kappa^{<\kappa}=\kappa$, let me outline the argument.

Assume $2^{<\kappa}=\kappa$, and let $\DeclareMathOperator\cf{cf}\{\mu_\alpha:\alpha<\cf(\kappa)\}$ be an increasing sequence of ordinals whose limit is $\kappa$. We may asume $\mu_0\ge\|T\|$. We build an elementary chain $\{\A_\alpha:\alpha<\cf(\kappa)\}$ of models of $T$ such that $|A_\alpha|\le2^{|\mu_\alpha|}$ as follows. We take for $\A_0$ any model of $T$ of cardinality $|\mu_0|$, and if $\gamma$ is limit, we put $\A_\gamma=\bigcup_{\alpha<\gamma}\A_\alpha$.

For the successor step, we let $\A_{\alpha+1}$ be an elementary extension of $\A_\alpha$ such that for every $X\subseteq A_\alpha$ of size $|\mu_\alpha|$, and every model $\A'$ of size $|\mu_{\alpha+1}|$ containing $X$ such that $(\A_\alpha,X)\equiv(\A',X)$, there exists an elementary embedding of $\A'$ in $\A_{\alpha+1}$ identical on $X$. These conditions on $\A_{\alpha+1}$ can be expressed as a certain first-order theory in a language with constants for all elements of all possible $\A'$s, which is easily shown to be consistent by compactness. In order to ensure $|A_{\alpha+1}|\le2^{|\mu_{\alpha+1}|}$, we need to bound the number of $\A'$s (up to isomorphism). There are $|A_\alpha|^{|\mu_\alpha|}\le(2^{|\mu_\alpha|})^{|\mu_\alpha|}=2^{|\mu_\alpha|}$ choices for $X$. For each $X$, there are $2^{|\mu_{\alpha+1}|}$ possible models $\A'$ with a fixed domain of size $|\mu_{\alpha+1}|$. Thus, the total number of possibilities for $\A'$ is $2^{|\mu_{\alpha+1}|}$, as required.

Now, let $\A=\bigcup_{\alpha<\cf(\kappa)}$, which is clearly a model of $T$ of size $\le2^{<\kappa}=\kappa$. In order to check that it is $\kappa^+$-universal, let $\B\models T$ be any model of size $\kappa$ (if it’s smaller, we take an elementary extension first). We can write $\B$ as a union of a chain $\{\B_\alpha:\alpha<\cf(\kappa)\}$ of elementary submodels such that $|B_\alpha|=|\mu_\alpha|$, and such that $\B_\gamma=\bigcup_{\alpha<\gamma}\B_\alpha$ for limit $\gamma$. By induction on $\alpha$, we construct elementary embeddings $f_\alpha\colon\B_\alpha\to\A_\alpha$ such that $\beta<\alpha\implies f_\beta\subseteq f_\alpha$, thus in the end, $f=\bigcup_{\alpha<\cf(\kappa)}f_\alpha$ is an elementary embedding of $\B$ in $\A$. In order to construct $f_{\alpha+1}$ from $f_\alpha$, we apply the defining property of $\A_{\alpha+1}$ with $X$ being the image of $f_\alpha$, and $\A'$ being $\B_{\alpha+1}$ (or rather, its copy with elements of $B_\alpha$ renamed to their $f$-images to make it literally include $X$).